# How to zoom in on portions of bar charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, crosstab

I have a df and need to do a cross-tabulation of two categorical features:  race and years of education.  Education started as a discrete feature but there were two many values so I custom binned them into five categorical bins.

So now there are five unique values for race, and five for education.  However, one of the values for race greatly exceeds all of the rest, so it's difficult to glean any information from my bar chart.

Any suggestions on how to set it up so that the bar chart (or multiple charts, if that would work better) is more readable?

!(C:\Users\chris\Desktop\Capture.png)

apologies if I can't get the picture of the chart to load properly

```
  ct_educrace=pd.crosstab(adult_df_educrace.race, adult_df_educrace.education_bins,margins=True)

  ct_educrace.plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: For a zoomable bar chart, you can consider using plotly.

Comment: Would a log scale help?

Comment: Log scale seems like your best option here.

Comment: Ok.  I'll look into these suggestions.  Thanks